# What is the opposite of "periodic boundary conditions"?

Tags: solid-state-physics, terminology, definition, boundary-conditions

I am writing a paper on solid-state physics and use periodic boundary conditions (PBC) for a calculation. To motivate why I use PBC, I write a paragraph about what would happen if I did not use PBC. I am looking for the proper term for non-periodic BC, meaning the system just ends.

I have read "open BC," but that seems to indicate that particles can leave through the edge, which is not the case in my system (I use a tight-binding description).

What is the proper term for the opposite of "periodic boundary conditions"?

Comment: You probably mean that your domain is a closed box, i.e. it sits on the bottom of an infinite potential well (the wavefunction and its gradient go to zero on the boundary). Note: both this system in the box and the one in PBC are "closed" (the only difference is that the "torus" is a manifold without boundaries, the box has boundaries).

Answer (score 1):

Well, I think it depends on what exactly you do NOT want to describe.

That being said, most people in condensed matter physics would probably understand "open boundary conditions" as essentially the system with an edge you described. Alternatively you could just call the other system a plane or something alike.

For completeness, I would call a system which can exchange particles with an environment an "open system" (independent of the choice of boundary conditions).

Answer (score 0):

There are many other possible boundary conditions, but I am not aware of any that will allow you to continue using Bloch's theorem. If you do not mind losing Bloch's theorem, then you can proceed.

Born von Karman periodic boundary conditions give you travelling waves. The usual opposite boundary conditions give you standing waves.

There are fixed end(point) Dirichlet boundary conditions, and free end Neumann boundary conditions. Note that Neumann is a different guy than von Neumann. You can also have mixed boundary conditions.

https://brilliant.org/wiki/applying-boundary-conditions-to-standing-waves/

https://galileo.phys.virginia.edu/classes/152.mf1i.spring02/Boundary%20Conditions.htm

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boundary_value_problem